# For some reason able to access value of input in js without document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, input, getelementbyid

```
function buttonPress()
{
    var userInput=document.getElementById('userInput');
    alert(userInput.value);
}
```

I removed

```
`var userInput=document.getElementById('userInput');`
```

and was left with

```
`alert(userInput.value);`
```

but the output did not change at all it was left the same, `userInput` is not even declared but it works. 
I cleaned all the data from browser,restarted the server, but result did not change, my brain is exploding, could it be because I am using the same name for id and the var?

Comment: can you share the full source code of your js?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In JavaScript, variables that are assigned a value but not declared are implicitly declared as a global variable.

Comment: How is this related to the question?